# How to create static preview of animated GIF using PHP and Imagick?

Tags: php, preview, imagick

I can't figure out how to create a static preview of animated GIF using Imagick module.
Is there a way to get a first frame of animated image and save as GIF?

Answer (score 6):

I've found a solution:

```
$image = new Imagick('animation.gif');
$image = $image->coalesceImages();
foreach ($image as $frame) {
    $frame->cropThumbnailImage(90, 90);
    break;
}
$frame->writeImage('frame.gif');
```

I didn't figured out how to reference first frame from image sequence, so had to do a loop and immediatelly break. If someone know how to do that, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in JavaScript check out: http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/

If you want to do this on the server side check out ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

though ImageMagick will need to be present of your server and PHP will have to be able to access it.

**Usage:**

```
convert 'image.gif[0]' singleframe.gif
```

Comment: Thanks, but since I'm already using PHP Imagick module in script, I would like solution based on that module too (without using external tools).